# Why can't the Klein bottle embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I'm working with the definition:

A smooth embedding of M into N is an injective immersion $F:M\rightarrow N$ that is also a topological embedding.

I'd like to explain why the klein bottle cant embed in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The immersion is not injective, thus results in self intersections, correct?

Comment: If you have self-intersection in a point $P$, how do you cope with the non-unicity of tangent space in $P$, for example ?

Comment: This reasoning raises the question why the immersion is not (cannot be) injective.

Comment: Are you asking why the "standard picture" of the Klein bottle is not an embedding? Or, instead, how to prove that there does not exist any embedding?

Comment: It suffices to make it kleiner und kleiner, thus at the end, we will not see the self intersection...

Comment: Argue that $F$ cannot be an immersion since that Klein bottle contains a copy of the Mobius strip.